# Problem with debugging PHP with Eclipse and xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Can you help me with the following problem? I have Eclipse Helios configured with xdebug under Ubuntu. When I start to debug a given page everything seems fine, I can attach to the break point I want, but the problem comes when I tray to step over/into, Firefox (my default browser for debugging) prompt me to "save as" the php page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to ensure that PHP, Apache and MySQL are running?

If they aren't running then you will not be able to run a PHP script.

I think the command in ubuntu (if not running on LAMPP) is "sudo apachectl start" to start apache/php

Then you can put your scripts in /var/www/html/

---

If you are running LAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) then you can probably "sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start" to boot everything up.

Then install your scripts to /opt/lampp/htdocs/

After you've done all of that, you should be able to run it.

Comment: I'm sure the Apache server with PHP are running because when I reload the page out of the debug session everything work fine.

Comment: Oh okay, well try and read this article, this may help you a lot : http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Apache as your webserver. If so, it seems that Apache doesn't know how to handle *.php files.

Have you added:

```
# Required modules: dir_module, php5_module

<IfModule dir_module>
    <IfModule php5_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

to your apache configuration file? This should do the trick.